# Should we use Constraintlayout as a Recyclerview item layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When i was implementing my recyclerview, I spent hours to find the reason why a random number of items where not shown in my view. They where just blank.
After I changed the recyclerview item layout from a constraint to a relative one, the problem was gone.
Everybody had the same issue?
Is there also a reason to avoid that layout, due the performance?

Comment: i don't think so its because of constraint layout.Can you add your code?

Comment: RelativeLayout is classified as a "legacy" layout by Android Studio. From the Android docs,  "The ConstraintLayout class offers similar layout control, but with much-improved performance".